# Importing a file (not a package) from a parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

My repository looks like:

```
example/
  main.py
  helpers.py
  plugins/
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

How can I import `helpers.py` in `foo.py` and `bar.py`? `from ..helpers import my_function` is not working returning `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

The issue here is that I just want to import a file, not a package.

Comment: put `example/` on your python path and reference it with `from helpers import my_function`

Comment: Read the error you get. Now think if this was allowed, what would happen if someone suddenly try to import the example package?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the path to sys.path

> import sys
>
> sys.path.append('your upper path')

Comment: Yes it will work, and yes it is the way to go. But you should warn future readers that this is a hack that can help in some use cases, but normally you should not need it. In fact, you should question your design when you have to do that.